# React App is not Deploying to Website after being placed on Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, server, cpanel

I am trying to create/upload/host a website and I am somewhat unfamiliar with the requirements/processes in place. I have created the start of a react app using the WebStorm React template, and now wish to add it to my domain server so I can test connecting it to a MySQL database.

I can run the app in development mode and it works. So, I ran "npm run build" and placed the resulting build folder onto my server using cPanel (hosted on GoDaddy). I thought this would deploy my app, but it still displays the default page of "If you're the site owner, log in to launch the site". Is this because there is no index.html file present?

My upload contains: server.js, package.json, assets.json, LICENSE.txt, yarn.lock, a "chunks" directory and a "public" directory.

Are there any large flaws in my thinking, is there anything else I need to do to deploy my React App? I have tried searches but nothing has resulted in what I need.

Comment: I don't know a lot about GoDaddy hosting.  I personally use Digital Ocean.  Does GoDaddy have an interface where you can run the terminal commands to start your server?

Comment: You might have uploaded the wrong directory. The content that you've listed sounds like the root directory. The build directory should contain static/, asset-manifest.json, favicon.ico, index.html, manifest.json and service-worker.js.